# getting 80th percentile from a data frame with Value and CDF

Tags: r, interpolation, probability

I have a data frame as follows

```
day<-c(1,1,2,2)
probability<-c(0.5,0.9,0.4,0.95)
demand<-c(2,8,4,9)
df<-data.frame(day,probability,demand)
```

I need to get the demand at the probability of 0.8. For which I need to interpolate the data
The output I am looking for is as follows:

```
day1 prob1 dem2
1   0.8 6.50
2   0.8 7.63
```

I think I need to use approx function, but am unable to get it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured the answer to the question.

```
result<-ddply(df,~day,summarise,demand1=approx(probability,demand,xout=0.8)$y)
```

will give the following data frame

```
day      demand1
1 6.500000
2 7.636364
```